# Detailed logging of OR-Tools VRP solver behaviour

Tags: or-tools, vehicle-routing, cp-sat

To better understand how the OR-Tools VRP solver arrives at a solution, I want to log each step in the search algorithm. The log must use terminology from the problem domain, not implementation specific terminology. For example, the log should print "nodes" instead of "indexes", as this makes it easier for a human to interpret the log.

Consider a VRPTW problem with 2 vehicles *V1, V2* and 7 locations *A, B, C, D, E, F, Z*; location *Z* is the depot. The cost of dropping a location is 10000.
Here is an example of how I imagine an ideal log output might look like:

```
BEGIN FIRST SOLUTION SEARCH WITH STRATEGY 'PARALLEL_CHEAPEST_INSERTION'
    assignment (objective value=60000): V1=[Z], V2=[Z], DROPPED=[A, B, C, D, E, F]
  INSERT CHEAPEST ARC: Z -> A
    assignment (objective value=51200): V1=[Z -> A -> Z], V2=[Z], DROPPED=[B, C, D, E, F]
  INSERT CHEAPEST ARC: Z -> C
    assignment (objective value=42800): V1=[Z -> A -> Z], V2=[Z -> C -> Z], DROPPED=[B, D, E, F]
  INSERT CHEAPEST ARC: A -> D
    assignment (objective value=33200): V1=[Z -> A -> D -> Z], V2=[Z -> C -> Z], DROPPED=[B, E, F]
  INSERT CHEAPEST ARC: D -> F
    assignment (objective value=25700): V1=[Z -> A -> D -> F -> Z], V2=[Z -> C -> Z], DROPPED=[B, E]
  INSERT CHEAPEST ARC: C -> E
    assignment (objective value=17100): V1=[Z -> A -> D -> Z], V2=[Z -> C -> E -> Z], DROPPED=[B]
  INSERT CHEAPEST ARC: D -> B
    assignment (objective value=9600): V1=[Z -> A -> D -> B -> Z], V2=[Z -> C -> E -> Z], DROPPED=[]
END FIRST SOLUTION SEARCH
BEGIN LOCAL SEARCH WITH META HEURISTIC 'AUTOMATIC => GREEDY_DESCENT'
  BEGIN ITERATION 1
    assignment (objective value=9600): V1=[Z -> A -> D -> B -> Z], V2=[Z -> C -> E -> Z], DROPPED=[]
    [0] EVALUATE OPERATOR 'RELOCATE_NEIGHBORS': V1, A >> 1
      assignment (objective value=9800): V1=[Z -> D -> A -> B -> Z], V2=[Z -> C -> E -> Z], DROPPED=[]
    [1] EVALUATE OPERATOR 'RELOCATE_NEIGHBORS': V1, A >> 2
      assignment (objective value=9100): V1=[Z -> D -> B -> A -> Z], V2=[Z -> C -> E -> Z], DROPPED=[]
    [2] EVALUATE OPERATOR 'RELOCATE_NEIGHBORS': V1, D >> 1
      assignment (objective value=REJECTED): V1=[Z -> A -> B -> D -> Z], V2=[Z -> C -> E -> Z], DROPPED=[]
        constraint violated: ArrivalTime(A) >= 8
    ...
    SELECT BEST NEIGHBOR: [1]
      assignment (objective value=9100): V1=[Z -> D -> B -> A -> Z], V2=[Z -> C -> E -> Z], 
  END ITERATION 1
  BEGIN ITERATION 2
    ...
END LOCAL SEARCH
```

What I tried so far:

- Setting [RoutingSearchParameters.log_search](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/8179abf8346b02c9aa39d356177fdbd6315f2c34/ortools/constraint_solver/routing_parameters.proto#L504-L513) to `true`. The log output doesn't tell my *which* branches were explored or *why* assignments were rejected.
- Adding an [AtSolutionCallback](https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/python/constraint_solver/pywrapcp#addatsolutioncallback). The callback is only called at the end of each iteration, but I'm interested in *all* assignments that were produced during an iteration; even the ones that violate a contraint or had a worse objective value.
- Set `solver.parameters.enumerate_all_solutions = True`, as suggested in the [CP-SAT tutorial](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver#finding_all_solutions).
- Creating a custom `SearchMonitor` class. But I'm at a loss where I would even have to start, since I'm not familiar with how the solver works internally.

Comment: You are mixing solvers, api, ...

Comment: @LaurentPerron I have a basic understanding of mathematical black box optimization, but I don't fully understand how these concepts map to the OR-Tools API. I hoped to learn more about the OR-Tools API by studying a the code that creates this log output.

Comment: I would start by looking at the code of examples. Or-tools contains different solvers with different API.

Comment: But what you ask is too much work, and will not be implemented.

Comment: @LaurentPerron Sorry for the misunderstanding, this is not a feature request! I guess some parts could be logged in userland code. The example above would be ideal, but even a partial solution would help me. If you can tell me which events/data are observable from userland code (and point me to the respective classes/methods), then I can implement the logger myself and share it here.